# QThread with QTimer connection issues

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qthread, qtimer

Is there anything wrong with this? It's giving me weird compilation errors:

> candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'void (QThread::*)(QThread::QPrivateSignal)' to 'const char *' for 2nd argument

```
QTimer timer;
timer.setInterval(3000);
connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &ThisClass::runConnectionCheck);
QThread connectionThread;
timer.moveToThread(&connectionThread);
connect(&connectionThread, &QThread::started, &timer, &QTimer::start);
connectionThread.start();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 `QTimer` slots called `start()`, so the compiler has that confusion, so you should `QOverload`:

```
connect(&connectionThread, &QThread::started, &timer, QOverload<>::of(&QTimer::start));
```

Or `static_cast<>()`:

```
connect(&connectionThread, &QThread::started, &timer,static_cast<void (QTimer::*)()>(&QTimer::start));
```

[@KubaOber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1329652/kuba-ober) provides 2 options:

C++14:

```
qOverload<>(&QTimer::start)
```

Lambda:

```
[&]{ timer.start(); }
```

Comment: You can also use `qOverload<>(&QTimer::start)` in C++14, or connect to the lambda `[&]{ timer.start(); }` :) Personally, I think that lambdas are more general constructs and require less Qt-specific knowledge to understand, and thus I prefer them - they make the source more maintainable by people without extensive Qt knowledge.

Comment: @KubaOber Interesting perspective, I will try to give that option in future solutions, on the other hand, in some cases it will be inconvenient to use lambdas ?, I am not sure but in the case that the transmitter of the signal lives in another thread different from the receiver.

Comment: Lambdas are just as usable no matter what the relative threads are. In most cases, there must be a `QObject` that determines the thread context in which the lambda is executing, as well as the lifetime of the lambda. Without the context, the lambda will live no longer than the signaling object. With the context, the lambda’s lifetime won’t exceed the lifetime of either sender nor context objects. I.e. `connect(sender, signal, receive_context, [&sender, &receive_context]{…})` – and the lambda won’t ever face dangling sender nor receive context pointers.

Comment: A good video from KDAB (2023) on that topic: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dugj-0xzZC4

Answer (score 1):

That you face this problem to begin with is the result of a complication you've added: *the connection is not necessary at all*. You can start the timer right away and then move it. The timer won't fire until the control returns to the event loop in the thread where the timer is, and that doesn't happen in your code since the timer is moved to another thread before your code returns to the event loop (if any) that this code runs on.

This code does the job just as well:

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/timer-move-start-53200294
#include <QtCore>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
   int fired = 0;

   QTimer timer;
   QThread connectionThread;
   QObject::connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, [&] {
      Q_ASSERT(QThread::currentThread() == &connectionThread);
      ++fired;
      timer.moveToThread(qApp->thread());  // move the timer back to allow destruction
      QCoreApplication::quit();
   });
   timer.start(3000);
   timer.moveToThread(&connectionThread);

   Q_ASSERT(!fired);
   connectionThread.start();
   app.exec();
   Q_ASSERT(fired);

   connectionThread.quit();
   connectionThread.wait();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
connect(&connectionThread, &QThread::started, &timer, &QTimer::start);
```

Because **QTimer::start** has two overloaded functions. You must use the old convention to point out which one to use.

```
connect(&connectionThread,SIGNAL(started()),&timer,SLOT(start()));
```

Comment: The use of Qt4 syntax is unnecessary, although of course it does work fine.

Comment: @KubaOber In my opinion, it's straight forward. You don't have to think too much. This really solves the problem.